# How to change/set the main view using Yeoman with Angular Fullstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I created a project using Yeoman (angular-fullstack). And now I would like to know how the change/set the main view to login.html. So normally when you start the application you first get the main view where you can chose to login or register. What I want is when the application start the page starts direct on the login.html

Answer (score 1):

in your app.js file located at `client\app\app.js`, in the angular config add the following:

```
$stateProvider
  .run(function ($state) {
    $state.go('login');
  });
```

So it should look like:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    $stateProvider
      .run(function ($state) {
        $state.go('login');
      });
  })
```

Comment: This assumes you picked ui-router as your router when you set up the project. Did you use ngRouter instead?

Comment: You should probably switch to ui-router, which is honestly way better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: you have any idea how to do it with ng route?

Comment: There's not an easy way, no. You'd probably have to do some kind of a logged in check in the authInterceptor and redirect to /login

Comment: ok so I added ui-route and I am using this one now. togheter with your code implemented i still can't change the main view to the login page ...

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has been out here for a while and you likely already have a good solution, but I was recently looking at this myself and see a couple options.

One, inside app.js you could add the following code snippet under $urlRouterProvider:

```
.when('/', '/login')
```

Making your full method be something like:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
       .when('/', '/login')

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
})
```

This would force anyone going to your base page url directly to login, unless they provide the full route to another page.  However, if you intend to still use the main.html, you will then need to go into client/app/main/main.js and change the default route to:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
 });
```

So main is reachable by appending /main to the url.

Which brings me to option 2: Go into the main.js file and switch it's url to '/main' and go into login.js and switch it's url to '/'.  Then anyone navigating to your base page automatically goes to the login screen but the url is viewed as just your domain without any sub page.

So client/app/main/main.js becomes:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
 });
```

And client/app/account/account.js now contains:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/account/login/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
 })
```