# How to change the main view using ui-route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With Yeoman I created an angular-fullstack project using the ui-route. And now I would like to know how the change the main view to login.html. So normally when you start the application you first get the main view where you can chose to login or register. What I want is when the application start the page starts direct on the login.html

Via this post -> [How to change/set the main view using Yeoman with Angular Fullstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501947/how-to-change-set-the-main-view-using-yeoman-with-angular-fullstack/31502085?noredirect=1#comment50968165_31502085) , I tried the following:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    $stateProvider
      .run(function ($state) {
        $state.go('login');
      });
  })
```

But when I implement this code then the main view page just goes blank and when I surf to http://localhost:900/login then I get a 304

Comment: do you have server set up for html5mode? Did you define a state with url for `login`? Not much routing shown

Comment: @charlietfl: yes i do

Comment: yes to config for login as url too?

Comment: @charlietfl: yes i believe so

Answer (score 1):

You can make login the default route:

```
   $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/login');
```

Comment: mmm I am getting an error from my console -> http://gyazo.com/3dff3792faf24febef6cf76c28d9f7c8

Comment: get rid of that run block then

Comment: @pro: yes when i get rid of that block then the application runs with no problems but its not achieving what i want. which is when the application starts it should show the login page not the main view

Answer (score 0):

For those who might come across the same issue as me. I found the solution. So basically  I just go to the main.js and change the code to

```
'use strict';

angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/account/login.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      });
  });
```

And in the app.js of the folder app you just change the following code

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

  })
```

TO:

```
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/login');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

  })
```